# Wiring Up pre-existing Docker container running Postgres with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

My goal is: Use a Docker container running a Postgres database.  Use this container for building the Spring Services and data access layer.   All of this is within my local environment.

I am working through setting up a Postgres database within a Docker container.  I have the container up and running.  I am have created the tables, views, triggers, sequences, etc.  It works fine from all I can tell.  I am able to connect using pgAdmin.

I have now moved to setting up Spring Boot, the Repository, the Model, and the unit test for a single table.  The test only inserts a couple of records into the table.   I have tried following several examples, tutorials and blogs.

When I build and test using maven for the project, I received the below error.

```
2020-08-10 16:01:49.407  INFO 83573 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-08-10 16:01:49.771  INFO 83573 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-08-10 16:01:49.789  INFO 83573 --- [           main] n.c.p.s.repository.VendorRepositoryTest  : Started VendorRepositoryTest in 6.623 seconds (JVM running for 7.917)
2020-08-10 16:01:49.932  INFO 83573 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
2020-08-10 16:01:50.660  INFO 83573 --- [           main] o.t.d.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy   : Accessing docker with local Unix socket
2020-08-10 16:01:50.661  INFO 83573 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Found Docker environment with local Unix socket (unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
2020-08-10 16:01:50.816  INFO 83573 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Docker host IP address is localhost
2020-08-10 16:01:50.871  INFO 83573 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 19.03.12
  API Version: 1.40
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 1991 MB
2020-08-10 16:01:51.966  INFO 83573 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
2020-08-10 16:01:51.966  INFO 83573 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Checking the system...
2020-08-10 16:01:51.967  INFO 83573 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
2020-08-10 16:01:52.131  INFO 83573 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : ✔︎ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space
2020-08-10 16:01:52.154  INFO 83573 --- [           main]  [postgres:9.6.12]                     : Creating container for image: postgres:9.6.12
2020-08-10 16:01:52.254  INFO 83573 --- [           main]  [postgres:9.6.12]                     : Starting container with ID: 0c1ea5de4bc47651ac2ce02d1e85590a9165d9c31b7584ea1924d88fc85eeaad
2020-08-10 16:01:52.614  INFO 83573 --- [           main]  [postgres:9.6.12]                     : Container postgres:9.6.12 is starting: 0c1ea5de4bc47651ac2ce02d1e85590a9165d9c31b7584ea1924d88fc85eeaad
2020-08-10 16:01:57.539  INFO 83573 --- [           main]  [postgres:9.6.12]                     : Container postgres:9.6.12 started in PT7.619S
Hibernate: select nextval ('vendor_tbl_vendor_id_seq')
2020-08-10 16:01:57.587 ERROR 83573 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "vendor_tbl_vendor_id_seq" does not exist
  Position: 17
Hibernate: select vendor0_.id as id1_0_, vendor0_.vendor_env as vendor_e2_0_, vendor0_.lpl_client_id as lpl_clie3_0_, vendor0_.public_key as public_k4_0_, vendor0_.secret_key as secret_k5_0_, vendor0_.vendor_name as vendor_n6_0_ from investor.vendor_tbl vendor0_
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.57 s <<< FAILURE! - in net.clouddeveloper.plaid.services.repository.VendorRepositoryTest
[ERROR] addVendor  Time elapsed: 8.052 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at net.clouddeveloper.plaid.services.repository.VendorRepositoryTest.addVendor(VendorRepositoryTest.java:84)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at net.clouddeveloper.plaid.services.repository.VendorRepositoryTest.addVendor(VendorRepositoryTest.java:84)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: relation "vendor_tbl_vendor_id_seq" does not exist
  Position: 17
        at net.clouddeveloper.plaid.services.repository.VendorRepositoryTest.addVendor(VendorRepositoryTest.java:84)

[ERROR] validateDatabaseRunning  Time elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started
        at net.clouddeveloper.plaid.services.repository.VendorRepositoryTest.performQuery(VendorRepositoryTest.java:56)
        at net.clouddeveloper.plaid.services.repository.VendorRepositoryTest.validateDatabaseRunning(VendorRepositoryTest.java:46)
```

From what I understand from the error, Spring Boot can not find the sequence for the table and the test can not prove can not prove the container is running.

[image: Docker Environment]
Here is how I create the image:

```
docker run --name plaid_postgres2 --rm -d -p 54321:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres  -e POSTGRES_DB=ach  postgres
```

This is more of the environment settings.
[image: Port & Mount]

Here is how I have the application properties setup:

```
# database connectivity
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:54321/ach
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

This is the Entity declaration.  Note I am using a sequence in Postgres for the specific table.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "investor", name="vendor_tbl")
public class Vendor  implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2343243243242432341L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="vendor_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(schema="investor",
                       name="vendor_tbl_vendor_id_seq",
                       sequenceName="vendor_tbl_vendor_id_seq",
                       allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,  generator="vendor_tbl_vendor_id_seq")
    private long vendor_id;
```

This is my Test Class:

```
public class VendorRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private VendorRepository repository;


   @Container
    private static final PostgreSQLContainer postgresqlContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer()
            .withDatabaseName("ach")
            .withUsername("postgres")
            .withPassword("postgres");


    @Test
    @DisplayName("Validate Database is Running")
    void validateDatabaseRunning() throws Exception {
        ResultSet resultSet = performQuery(postgresqlContainer, "SELECT 1");
        resultSet.next();
        int result = resultSet.getInt(1);
        assertEquals(1, result);

        assertTrue(postgresqlContainer.isRunning());
    }

    private ResultSet performQuery(PostgreSQLContainer protgres, String query) throws SQLException {

        String jdbcURL = postgresqlContainer.getJdbcUrl();
        String userName = postgresqlContainer.getUsername();
        String password = postgresqlContainer.getPassword();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, userName, password);
        return conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);

    }


    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test Find All Vendors")
    public void find_all_vendors() {
        Iterable<Vendor> vendors = repository.findAll();

        int numOfCities =4;
        assertThat(vendors).isEmpty(); //.hasSize(numOfCities);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test Add Vendor")
    public void addVendor(){
        String clientID = "blahblahblah";
        String secret_key = "blahblah";
        String public_key = "blahblah";
        String environment = "blah";
        String vendor_name = "Russ Test";
        Vendor vendor1 = new Vendor(clientID, secret_key, public_key, environment, vendor_name);
        Vendor vendor2 = new Vendor(clientID, secret_key, public_key, environment, vendor_name);
        this.repository.save(vendor1);
        this.repository.save(vendor2);
    }


}
```

After of two days of searching for answers, I have lost direction on how to resolve.  Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Russ

Comment: postgres usually runs on port 5432, did you set 54320 on purpose or a typo? Also please share you dockerfile and docker run command

Comment: The docker run command is redirecting the port.  I am using the Spring Boot server running locally and connecting to the Docker Container where the database is running.  Is docker file required?

Comment: I'm confused: what do you mean by "I have the container up and running. I have created the tables, views, triggers, sequences, etc.". From what I can see in the logs, you are using `testcontainers` so you are starting a new postgres on each run. The question is what you are actually connecting to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use Dockerfile but you need to define and pass to Docker container username, password and database name. You could do that also in the run command:

`docker run --rm --name postgresContainer -d -p 54320:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=yourDatabase postgres`

default username is postgres so you don't need to specify that. Last postgres word in command is the name of the image

I also called yourDatabase differently because I think there is a default database in postgres called postgres.

After running the above command you can execute the following to check that your database is running:

`docker exec -it postgresContainer bash`

`su postgres`

`psql`

`\list`

This will show you all of the databases available. Now type:

`\c yourDatabase`

and you are connected to your database in postgres Docker. Feel free to run create tables/selects or whatever.

to exit just type `\q` and `exit` like 2 times. Container will keep running.

---

Don't forget to update you spring properties to match

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:54320/yourDatabase
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

also I think you should remove the `schema` parameter from your java code, I never used it and I am afraid it will start searching for 'investor' database.

Comment: First of all, thank you!  I created a new docker image.  I did the cli commands and yes that all worked. I created only one table, one sequence, one table trigger and one trigger function.  I updated the application.properties file. I ensured the all privileges for the the database items.   I re-ran the mvn clean package command.    I am still getting the same error.

Comment: This is the error from the Docker Desktop:  2020-08-10 22:26:01.581 UTC [185] ERROR: relation "vendor_tbl_vendor_id_seq" does not exist at character 17

2020-08-10 22:26:01.581 UTC [185] STATEMENT: select nextval ('vendor_tbl_vendor_id_seq')

Comment: Removing the schema declaration created the table under the public schema.  All needs to remain under the same schema.

Comment: Since the errors happen in tests can you show ur tests? Also are you using the same Postgres dB or do you have an embedded dB?

Comment: Added test cases. Update the docker image.  Created new database to prove hypothesis.

Comment: I feel like we can limit the problem to the `@GeneratorSequence `- just to see if I am right, can you try removing `@GeneratorSequence `  and change `GeneratedValue` to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

Comment: @J Asgarov, you are correct!   Got it up and running. Thank you VERY MUCH!  Would it be fair to say I may have stumbled across a bug with the @SequenceGenerator annotation?

Comment: Lol unfortunately it is much more likely that you have made a mistake setting it up:) Don't have much experience with creating custom sequences but you can consult Hibernate Documentation (Spring JPA is based on Hibernate)

Comment: Okay.  Had to change the dialect to: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect.  I updated the entity with:
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "vendor_seq",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value ="vendor_tbl_vendor_id_seq"),
                    @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                    @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1"),
                    @Parameter(name = "schema", value = "investor")})